# How do I add text to a paragraph tag via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, google-chrome-extension, append

I'm trying to write my first chrome extension to test my acquired knowledge from codecademy (HTML/CSS, JQUERY and Javascript). First of all I'm trying to append text to a paragraph tag via the  onclick of a button.

heres my code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Facebook event graph</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="inputUrl">
                Enter a URL:  <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
                <button type="button" onclick="getFacebookData()"> Get Data </button>
        </form>
        <canvas id="graph" width="300" height="100">   
        </canvas> 
        <p id="text" width="300" height="100">1</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my popup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Variables
    function getFacebookData() {
        $('p').append('Test');
    };
});
```

it's probably something very basic that I'm doing wrong, but a push in the right direction would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Please also post your manifest.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are [not allowed to use inline scripting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) like `onclick="getFacebookData()"`

   You have to remove the handler from html:

   ```
   <button type="button" id="my-button"> Get Data </button>
   ```

   And you have to move the handler into popup.js:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#my-button').click(getFacebookData);
   });
   ```
2. You are also, by default, not allowed to load jQuery from an external CDN - and certainly not http one, again for Content Security Policy reasons. And you shouldn't! Put jQuery in your extension's folder and load it locally.
3. Matter of taste, but I would place `getFacebookData()` definition outside `$(document).ready`, so it's available in the global scope. Also, the semicolon after it is not needed.

Last, but not least: for future [debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging), inspect the console of the corresponding page of your extension. For things like background/options page you should be able to access them from Developer Mode extensions list. For a popup, you should right-click the button of your extension and select "Inspect Popup".

Comment: Also code doesnt go in popup. Goes into content script.

Comment: @user3512870 Glad it worked for you! Please mark the answer as accepted, so that the question counts as closed.

Comment: I do however get an error upon inspecting the extension in chrome "$ is not defined" in my popup.js any idea?

Comment: @AxiΩmega This means jQuery is not loaded, or loaded too late. Did you put its file in the correct place? Did you reload the extension after doing that?

Comment: @Xan inside my extension folder are 4 files (manifest, popup.js, popup.html and icon.png). And yes I reloaded the extension

Comment: @Xan okay I have a local copy of JQuery and now it loads and all. But it appends "test" to my paragraph without clicking the button. And clicking the button does nothing. I've tried placing it back in the $(document).ready but that didn't work

Comment: @Xan could I add you on G+ or something to ask you some more questions regarding extensions?

Comment: @AxiΩmega leave contact information in your profile, I'll contact you.